# How to add basic world collision with PhaserJS?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I am working on a new game using the PhaserJS library for HTML5 and am at a loss with a problem I've run into. I'm using the P2 physics engine for basic platform physics and I'm unable to get the world bounds collision to work. Here is my code:

Game.js

```
function create() {
    game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 300);
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);
    game.physics.p2.restitution = 0.8;

    player.create(game);
    player.instance.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
}
```

Player.js

```
Player.prototype.create = function(game) {
    this.instance = game.add.sprite(100, 100, 'player');
    game.physics.p2.enable(this.instance, Phaser.Physics.P2JS);

    this.cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
};
```

Right now my understanding is that I need to set the world bounds by calling "game.world.setBounds(width, height)" and then check bounds by calling "player.instance.body.collideWorldBounds = true;", but the player sprite is still going right through the boundaries. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I'm using PhaserJS 2.0.7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to update to Phaser [2.1.1](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/master/build/phaser.js), as it looks like they have this issue fixed in there.

You can see that from [this example](http://examples.phaser.io/_site/view_full.html?d=p2%20physics&f=collide%20world%20bounds.js&t=collide%20world%20bounds&phaser_version=v2.1.1&).

Here's the source code for that example:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', { preload: preload, create: create, update: update });

function preload() {

    game.load.image('stars', 'assets/misc/starfield.jpg');
    game.load.spritesheet('ship', 'assets/sprites/humstar.png', 32, 32);

}

var ship;
var starfield;
var cursors;

function create() {

    starfield = game.add.tileSprite(0, 0, 800, 600, 'stars');

    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);

    game.physics.p2.restitution = 0.8;

    ship = game.add.sprite(200, 200, 'ship');
    ship.scale.set(2);
    ship.smoothed = false;
    ship.animations.add('fly', [0,1,2,3,4,5], 10, true);
    ship.play('fly');

    //  Create our physics body. A circle assigned the playerCollisionGroup
    game.physics.p2.enable(ship);

    ship.body.setCircle(28);

    //  This boolean controls if the player should collide with the world bounds or not
    ship.body.collideWorldBounds = true;

    cursors = game.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

}

function update() {

    ship.body.setZeroVelocity();

    if (cursors.left.isDown)
    {
        ship.body.moveLeft(200);
    }
    else if (cursors.right.isDown)
    {
        ship.body.moveRight(200);
    }

    if (cursors.up.isDown)
    {
        ship.body.moveUp(200);
    }
    else if (cursors.down.isDown)
    {
        ship.body.moveDown(200);
    }

}
```

Comment: That might be possible that version 2.0.7 might be causing me a few problems, and I wasn't aware of a newer version, honestly. I'll try this out tonight and let you know if it works for me. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

In my game I had to call `p2.setBoundsToWorld` to update the p2 physics bounds to match the world bounds:

```
function create() {
    game.world.setBounds(0, 0, 800, 300);
    game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.P2JS);
    game.physics.p2.setBoundsToWorld(true, true, true, true, false);
```

The signature is as follows:

```
setBoundsToWorld: function (left, right, top, bottom, setCollisionGroup)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of that method, actually. I'll give it a shot tonight and see if I get any results. Thanks for your answer.